# Digital Publishing Suite Web Viewer not showing App

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-dps

I am trying to make a webpage that will show my Digital Publishing Suite app that I have made. I have made the app and it works fine on iPad and Android. When I try to add it too a webpage using the web viewer and Adobes demo I get the error "The article cannot be located. A valid URL is required". I have changed the code so that it includes my Adobe ID etc and no luck. Here is the code that is currently on my webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Bridge Demo</title>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jsdist/WVEmbed.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-contentviewer.adobe.com/public/pepper/wvel/2/WVEmbed.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="mainContainer">
    <!-- Iframe destination -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var wvQueryParamGroups = location.search.match(/[?&^#]wv=(s[\/%\-.\w]+)/),
    wvQueryParam = wvQueryParamGroups && wvQueryParamGroups.length === 2 ? decodeURIComponent(wvQueryParamGroups[1]) : null;

    function eventCallback (message) {
        console.log(message);
        return true;
    }

    function errorCallback (message) {
        console.log(message);
        return true;
    }

    function redirectCallbackHandler (message) {
        console.log(message); 
    }

    var bridge = adobeDPS.frameService.createFrame({
        boolIsFullScreen : false,
        parentDiv : 'mainContainer',
        wrapperClasses : 'uniqueFrame',
        iframeID : 'demoFrame',
        accountIDs : 
        '2feacb12-3971-57e9-aab4-cce431a01dcd', 
        wvParam : wvQueryParam ? wvQueryParam : 
    '/s/Armagh%20GAA%20Club%20and%20County/2feacb12-3971-57e9-aab4-cce431a01dcd/Armagh%20GAA/Cover.html',
        curtainClasses : 'mask hidden', 
        eventCallback : eventCallback, 
        errorCallback : errorCallback,
        redirectCallback : redirectCallbackHandler,
        footer : [
            'Copyright ©2013 Adobe Systems Inc. All Rights use to be Reserved'
        ]
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to double check your account ID is correct. The account ID should be the ID used to publish your folios.

> '/s/Armagh%20GAA%20Club%20and%20County/2feacb12-3971-57e9-aab4-cce431a01dcd/Armagh%20GAA/Cover.html'

Answer (score 0):

To embed your content on your own site, ensure that you set the hosting URL in your publication account's settings to the URL that you will host it on.